# USING LIKE inside pandas.query()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been using Pandas for more than 3 months and I have an fair idea about the dataframes accessing and querying etc.

I have got an requirement wherein I wanted to query the dataframe using LIKE keyword (LIKE similar to SQL) in **pandas.query().**

i.e:
Am trying to execute **pandas.query("column_name LIKE 'abc%'")** command but its failing.

I know an alternative approach which is to use str.contains("abc%") but this doesn't meet our requirement.

We wanted to execute LIKE inside pandas.query(). How can I do so?

Comment: It's been a while since this question was posted: has a solution to this been found or is this still only obtainable through `str.contains()`?

Comment: For those new to Pandas. Look at the docs for Series object like Pandas.series.str.contains: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 99):

If you have to use df.query(), the correct syntax is:

```
df.query('column_name.str.contains("abc")', engine='python')
```

You can easily combine this with other conditions:

```
df.query('column_a.str.contains("abc") or column_b.str.contains("xyz") and column_c>100', engine='python')
```

It is not a full equivalent of SQL Like, however, but can be useful nevertheless.

Comment: Does not work for me with Pandas version 0.24.2 without the added `, engine='python'` as @P.Panayotov mentioned. Moreover, using `pandas` over `df` might confuse beginners.

Comment: Good suggestions - made a few changes

Comment: just a reminder: text in `str.contains()` is a **regex** by default

Comment: "If you have to use df.query", is there a better way (or different?) than .query if one wants to filter within a method chain?

Comment: @Bouchner I didn't need to add engine = 'python,' probably because it's almost 3 years later and I'm using Pandas 1.4.1.

Answer (score 33):

@volodymyr is right, but the thing he forgets is that you need to set engine='python' to expression to work.

Example:

```py
>>> pd_df.query('column_name.str.contains("abc")', engine='python')
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-query) is more information on default engine ('numexpr') and 'python' engine. Also, have in mind that 'python' is slower on big data.

Comment: Edit: Can confirm this worked for me, after setting engine to python. Take care to use " and ' in the correct order.

Answer (score 14):

Not using query(), but this will give you what you're looking for:

```
df[df.col_name.str.startswith('abc')]


df
Out[93]: 
  col_name
0     this
1     that
2     abcd

df[df.col_name.str.startswith('abc')]
Out[94]: 
  col_name
2     abcd
```

Query uses the pandas [eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval) and is limited in what you can use within it.  If you want to use pure SQL you could consider [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql) where the following statement would work for you:

```
sqldf("select col_name from df where col_name like 'abc%';", locals())
```

Or alternately if your problem with the pandas `str` methods was that your column wasn't entirely of string type you could do the following:

```
df[df.col_name.str.startswith('abc').fillna(False)]
```

Comment: I have tried SQLDF, this is solving my problem however i am seeing huge performance issue with it. I added 95lakhs of records with regular df.query() i could get the result in 1min. but if i use SQLDF its taking minimum 10mins.

Comment: SQLDF creates and tears down an sqlite database hence the performance hit.  Is there a reason you can't use startswith()?

Answer (score 9):

Super late to this post, but for anyone that comes across it. You can use boolean indexing by making your search criteria based on a string method check `str.contains`.

Example:

```
dataframe[dataframe.summary.str.contains('Windows Failed Login', case=False)]
```

In the code above, the snippet inside the brackets refers to the summary column of the dataframe and uses the `.str.contains` method to search for `'Windows Failed Login'` within every value of that Series. Case sensitive can be set to true or false. This will return boolean index which is then used to return the dataframe your looking for. You can use `.fillna()` with this in the brackets as well if you run into any Nan errors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't have a summary column, so for a random column name one can use `new_df = df[df['Column'].str.contains('something')]`

Answer (score 4):

A trick I just came up with for "starts with":

```
pandas.query('"abc" <= column_name <= "abc~"')
```

**Explanation:** pandas accepts "greater" and "less than" statements for strings in a query, so anything starting with "abc" will be greater or equal to "abc" in the lexicographic order. The tilde (~) is the largest character in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), so anything starting with "abc" will be less than or equal to "abc~".

A few things to take into consideration:

- This is of course case sensitive. All lower case characters come after all upper cases characters in the ASCII table.
- This won't work fully for Unicode strings, but the general principle should be the same.
- I couldn't come up with parallel tricks for "contains" or "ends with".

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame:

```
    Name    Code  App

0  Jhon     8010  google
1  Michael  9020  github
2  Mandy    1240  google.com
3  Krish    1240  facebook
```

Search a word or related words in Dataframe

`S = df[df["column_name"].str.contains("word")]`
`S.head()`

Example:

```
Myword = input("Enter the word, want to search:")

S = df[df["App"].str.contains(Myword)]
S.head()

print(S)
```

Output:

```
Enter the word, want to search: google
```

```
   Name   Code  App
0  Jhon   8010  google
2  Mandy  1240  google.com
```

> Note: This method is case sensitive