# Pandas DataFrame query LIKE operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I do something like this?

```
query_string = "parameter_1 LIKE '%text%' | parameter_2 LIKE '%text2%'"
raw_data.query(query_string )
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391275/using-like-inside-pandas-query

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I need to do it in a single string

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
query_string = 'parameter_1.str.contains("text") or parameter_2.str.contains("text2")'
raw_data.query(query_string)
```