# Importing Text Data From MySQL Workbench, End Up With More Rows Than I Began With

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, mysql-workbench

I am running into the issue where I am unable to import my result table from MySQL Workbench into a pandas data frame.

My first try was to use mysql.connector

```
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd
db_connection = mysql.connect(#All the info necessary)
df = pd.read_sql(#Query)
```

Issue with the solution was in my query I wanted to filter out rows that had certain words in them. So my query in MySQL Workbench looks something like this:

```
select text_column from table where date < '2000-01-01' and date > '1999-12-31' and not( text_column like % cat % or text_column like % dog % .. and so on and so forth...) order by rand() limit 5
```

From my understanding you cannot do that type of querying using pandas. I looked at this question to get that answer: [USING LIKE inside pandas.query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391275/using-like-inside-pandas-query)

I have to much data that I cannot just pull down the result table and then get the rows that are appropriate.

The next step was exporting the resulting table from MySQL Workbench and then use pandas to import it.

I first try exporting it using the .xls file extension. The issue I ran into there was that it was not encoding the strings correctly, I would lose information. Since I have a Mac, there is no way for me to import this data using utf-8 encoding. Please see this website for further https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16

From there I tried to export it as a .csv but I run into two issues. One is because these are text columns, I run into the issue that there is more than one field where there should only be one. If the separator is a comma or a semi colon, it still appears in text and will separator text that should be seen as one cell.

Even without dealing with the separators, the data does not export correctly. This is because some of the text has new line characters. When exporting, that is read in as a new row.

So how can I export this result table with one column of only text from MySQL Workbench properly? I would prefer not to have to manipulate the file by hand.

Comment: read_csv takes an encoding option to deal with files in different formats. I mostly use read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), or alternatively encoding = "utf-8" for reading, and generally utf-8 for to_csv

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: without looking at data it's difficult to comment, share some sample data in the Question.

Comment: Okay, will do :)